# Expanding array variables

Tags: batch-file

I have an issue with expanding array variables. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
set array[0]=a
set array[1]=b
set array[2]=c

 FOR /l %%x IN (0 1 2) do curl  -XGET  -H "Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%" "https://baseURL/%array[%%x]%/params" -H "content-type: application/json" > %%x.json
```

I have tried using delayedexpansion, but it didn't help either

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /l %%x IN (0 1 2) do curl  -XGET  -H "Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%" "https://baseURL/!array[%%x]!/params" -H "content-type: application/json" > %%x.json
```

I've tried many variations including

```
!array[%%x]!
!%array[%%x]%!
!%array[!%x%!]%!
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Of course that `!array[%%x]!` should work! All this management is explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have messed up this in your side. The correct would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set array[0]=a
set array[1]=b
set array[2]=c

for /L %%A IN (0 1 2) do curl  -XGET  -H "Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%" "https://baseURL/!array[%%A]!/params" -H "content-type: application/json" > %%A.json
```